# How to call a linux command in Python without waiting for the results (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, raspbian

Is there a way to call a linux shell commands via Python without having to wait for its completion?
I have seen threads to do that in a Windows environment, but not for Linux (Raspbian)...

Comment: doesn't [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) should do the trick.

```
from subprocess import Popen
process = Popen(['sleep', '10'])
print 'Returned immediately!'
```

Comment: Does it live even after my python application is killed?

Comment: @user1688175 -- doubtful.  The subprocess is likely created as a child of the python process.  When a parent gets killed, the child dies with it.  You can however, `atexit.register(process.wait)` -- Now python will wait for that process to complete before the python process exits.

Comment: I actually would like to start a C application which monitors the python application. For instance I want to capture if the python application is up... Do you have any idea how to start both applications independently and automatically during the boot?

Comment: @user1688175 -- Nope, that's beyond my sys-admin skills... It seems like the two should be started together (e.g. via a shell script) rather than having a python script start a C program that monitors the python script.  But I've not ever set up a shell script to execute during system boot -- Although I imagine that it shouldn't be _too_ hard to find a post somewhere on the internet demonstrating how to do that...

Comment: FYI: I found it! In the Raspian,you have to edit the /etc/rc.local file and add both commands followed by a " &" before the instruction "exit 0".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('echo "test" > a', shell=True)
```